# Django admin panel logout functionality

Tags: python, django, admin

Is there any way to logout from all devices where I have logged in as admin in Django admin panel?
The site has already been deployed to heroku server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can manually delete all sessions you have in your database.

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
Session.objects.delete()
```

Answer (score -1):

- There is no such option, one idea is to delete that user and recreate super user.
- Change superuser password.